# Linking shared libraries with executables

Tags: c++, boost, compilation, g++, shared-libraries

I have a small doubt in the compilation of a c++ code along with a shared library.

So I have two files `main.cpp` and `sample.cpp`.

## main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "sample.h"

myStruct obj;

void populateData() {
        obj.s = "hello world";
}

myStruct giveData() {
        cout << "Inside main: " << obj.s << endl;
        return obj;
}

int main() {
        populateData();
}
```

## sample.h

```
#ifndef SAMPLE_H
#define SAMPLE_H

#include <string>

struct myStruct {
        std::string s;
        void populateData();
};

myStruct giveData();

#endif
```

## sample.cpp

```
#include "sample.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/python.hpp>

using namespace std;

void myStruct :: populateData() {
        cout << giveData().s;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(boosts) {
        using namespace boost::python;

        class_<myStruct>("struct")
                .add_property("s", &myStruct::s)
                .def("populateData", &myStruct::populateData)
        ;
}
```

I compile the program using

```
g++ -c -fPIC sample.cpp
g++ -c -fPIC main.cpp
g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,boosts.so -o boosts.so sample.o main.o -lpython2.7 -lboost_python
g++ -o main main.o
./main
```

Now, when I run the `main`, it populates the `string` inside the `obj`. But when I run a python script, that imports the `boosts.so`, the `obj.s` is empty.

I am guessing it is because the library `boosts.so` is not properly linked with the executable `main`.

How do I fix this?

Comment: When you run `main` it populates `string` inside of the `obj`. But this `obj` exists inside of `main` process and gets vanished after process exits.

Comment: Well, the obj is declared as global scope. So I guess that should be no problem

Comment: Or I even tried with threads, making the `main` wait till I access the obj inside the python. Still no luck.

Comment: That is not going to work because `main` and python run in different processes. If you need to share data between processes then you need some form of IPC, you can utilize `boost::interprocess` for example.

Comment: "I am guessing it is because the library boosts.so is not properly linked with the executable main"
It isn't linked with executable `main` *at all*. On the other hand,
the object file `main.o` *is* linked into the shared library, which makes no sense.
It's quite unclear what you are thinking or trying to do.

Comment: My aim is to get the changes in `main` to get reflected in the shared library `boosts.so` so that they can be accessed in a python script